# About inheritance and constructors

Tags: c#

I just wondering if this code is correct that I found in some information. The thing I find strange, is that diameter is used twice in both example, is this really correct?

```
public Ellipse(double diameter): base(diameter, diameter)
```

Comment: Why do you find it strange? What is the base class?

Comment: Presumably it is just saying "a default ellipse is a circle" - I'm guessing there is a second constructor that takes two parameters.

Comment: Why downvote my qustion? I just thought it was strange that there was two 'diameter' and I was thinking of common fields that can't be two of the same name, but now when I see your code, it understand it better and that it's Ok to have a 'diameter' twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is correct. The classes might look something like that:

```
public class Base
{
  public Base(double d1, double d2)
  {
  }
}

public Eclipse : Base
{
   public Ellipse(double diameter)
        : base(diameter, diameter)
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the constructor of an `Ellipse` class, it calls the base class constructor which has two parameters.

It could look something like this:

```
class Shape
{
 public Shape(double diameter1, double diameter2)
 {
 }
}
class Ellipse : Shape
{
 public Ellipse(double diameter) : base(diameter, diameter)
 {
 }
}
```

If you do `new Ellipse(10);` 10 is passed into the Ellipse constructor, which calls the `Shape` class constructor and passes 10 as the arguments for both those params.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what the base class constructor does with the parameters, but syntactically, it's correct.

The code you posted calls the base class constructor that matches the supplied arguments instead of the default base class constructor (if any).

Answer (score 1):

This is constructor chaining i.e. calling base constructor before child constructor.

If base class has a constructor like

```
public Base(double, double)
```

then it is perfectly fine.